# Characterizing a function regarding symmetry

Tags: functions, symmetry

Let us suppose a function $f \colon \mathbb{N} \times \mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{R}$, such that $$\neg\left(\forall a,b \,|\, a \in N \land b \in N \implies f(a,b)=f(b,a)\right)$$ That is $$\left(\exists a,b \,|\, a \in N \land b \in N \land f(a,b)\neq f(b,a)\right)$$
I'm not sure if I can say that f is non-symmetric. Can I?
I know that a I can use symmetric, asymmetric, anti-symmetric for characterizing relations. But I think that when I'm working with functions, the reasoning is not the same.

Thank you in advance for your attention.

Best regards.

Comment: Yes, you can call it non-symmetric: https://encrypted.google.com/books?id=qkmG04_ecLMC&pg=PA230&lpg=PA230&dq=E.J.+Lemmon+Beginning+Logic&source=bl&ots=_EuIeHzEHz&sig=iTPpodb1KR8iiQXXLkCE9bfKAtI&hl=en&sa=X&ei=5tWsU_T0NI6xuATi1IDYAg&ved=0CDsQ6AEwAw#v=onepage&q=non-symmetric&f=false

Comment: You should specify "non-symmetric in its arguments".

Comment: Thank you M. Vinay. I didn't know the notion of"non-symmetric in its arguments".